# Installing boost via vcpkg, I get the wrong toolset

Tags: c++, boost, vcpkg

I recently switched from using the Visual Studio 2015 IDE to the Visual Studio 2019 IDE. Around that same time I started using vcpkg for library installations. I've been using a pre-build version of an earlier version of boost, which I compiled myself. Thinking I ought to switch to a newer version of boost using vcpkg, I installed it with:

```
vcpkg.exe install boost --triplet x64-windows-static
```

Yet when I look inside C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\lib I see that vc140 - *the Visual Studio 2015 toolset* - is the version of boost built. **Note that I am not using cmake. I am working purely in the IDE. How do I tell vcpkg I want the vc142 toolset, the version for Visual Studio 2019, built?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is a modified version of the [GitHub issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues/1234#issuecomment-306907668),

Edit file from your VCPKG path

```
vcpkg\triplets\x86-windows.cmake
```

To add line

```
set(VCPKG_PLATFORM_TOOLSET v142)
```

Comment: Do I need to uninstall and reinstall a given library after adding this line? After editing and saving the x64-windows-static.cmake (the triplet I'm building), running the same command I show in my original post returns the package is already installed.

Comment: Looks like one needs to create separate .cmake files. I modified my x64-windows-static.cmake to be two files x64-windows-static-140.cmake and x64-windows-static-142.cmake files. Then I requested a build with "vcpkg install boost:x64-windows-static-v140 boost:x64-windows-static-v142" and that seems to be the trick...

Comment: Yeah, pain in the butt - it built the 140 libs, not the 142. I've reverted to hand building boost.

Comment: @BlakeSenftner Why did you specify the two triplets together? `"vcpkg install boost:x64-windows-static-v140 boost:x64-windows-static-v142"` I think it's the reason you got two type of builds.

Comment: @prehistorispenguin my searching found a github issue discussing this same goal, and in the solution they posted it had install requests with multiple triplets. So that's what I tried... Trying again now with individual install requests for each triplet. (To be honest, building boost itself is easier than figuring out vcpkg. The vcpkg documentation is some of the worst I seen; clearly written by people that do not know how to write documentation.

Comment: @BlakeSenftner haha, I would like to blame Microsoft too, they make it too hard to uninstall the visual studio, or we can just uninstall the vs2015, then everything would be fine.